# Command-line browser with support for javascript rendering which outputs only the rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, browser, command-line, webkit, qtwebkit

I want a fast way to retrieve a page given a URL, but not getting only the simple HTML, but the HTML after executing javascript.

I'm aware of [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), but for me it is slow, taking more than 10 seconds for some web pages. Also I'm not comfortable using the --min-wait option, as it can return empty/non-final HTMLs. Also it seems to give different HTMLs from time to time. Sometimes it renders a element which is created by a javascript function, sometimes it does not.

Is there any alternatives? I want to give an URL and get the rendered html back.

Comment: Why do you think that this is possible in less time? If that app takes 10 seconds, it seems to take 10 seconds. You won't be able to get this done in a few milliseconds, for sure. Browsers and JavaScript implementations are complex things.

Comment: Because a browser like chrome can do it in less than 5 seconds! Also, the issue cited in the question: "Also it seems to give different HTMLs from time to time. Sometimes it renders a element which is created by a javascript function, sometimes it does not."

Comment: You can use WebKit and build your own one. Shouldn't be too difficult if you know how to use Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the current version of CutyCapt from the svn repository and compile it with Qt 4.7.1 (or the trunk version from the [Qt git repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/). The current Webkit implementation is faster than version 4.4.0 that is used in the compiled version of CutyCapt. If it still is not fast enoupgh you could profile the code and try to find out if it can be optimized.